# Highlight only current bullet in beamer in reusable fashion

Tags: beamer

The first frame shows exactly the output that I want, but I don't like to use the manual `\onslide<n>` because it would be a bad idea if I think of a new text in between `text2` and `text3`, for example, where I would need to change the numbers manually then. Is there a neater way to achieve the same functionality without using manual numbers?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}

\begin{document}

\setbeamercovered{still covered={\opaqueness<1->{0}},again covered={\opaqueness<1->{10}}}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item \onslide<1> {text1}
    \item \onslide<2> {text2}
    \item \onslide<3> {text3}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item text1
    \item text2
    \item text3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

The items may have sub-items: For example, between `text2` and `text3`:

```
\item newitem
\begin{itemize}
    \item newtext
    \item newtext
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\item` macro can use overlay specifications.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=25}
\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{still covered={\opaqueness<1->{0}},again covered={\opaqueness<1->{10}}}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Manual}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item \onslide<1> {text1}
    \item \onslide<2> {text2}
    \item \onslide<3> {text3}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Semi-automatic}
  \begin{itemize}[<+>]
  \item<+-+(3)> text1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<+-> test1
    \item<+-> test2
    \item<+-> test3
    \end{itemize}
  \item text2
    \begin{itemize}[<.->]
    \item test1
    \item test2
    \item test3
    \end{itemize}
  \item text3
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works well but seems to be problematic if one of the items had subitems. Please see example in updated question.

Comment: @Curious I updated my answer...

Comment: Thanks @Paul. It looks good. So is there no way to fully automate this?

Comment: @Curious A fully automatic solution with progressive subitems seems difficult to achieve.